# Is there real analogue for Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

For example,
$$\frac{3}{z^2-5z+4}$$
has a Laurent series expansion on the angular region $1<|z|<4$. Does the real function
$$\dfrac{3}{x^2-5x+4}$$
have some sort of Laurent series on $(-4,-1)\cup (1,4)$?

I'm taking complex analysis, but I have almost no experience with series from calculus. It wasn't in the curriculum. I really need to fill in this gap in my math knowledge :(

Comment: It's an unfortunate trend these days to put all kinds of peripheral topics into calculus courses and make up for that by neglecting series, which should be one of the central topics of calculus.  Complex analysis can be a good place to make up for this omission - radius of convergence, for example, is much nicer in the complex case anyway.  But the need to do this should be taken into account when writing the syllabus for the complex analysis course.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: +1. What's the point in learning about meromorphic functions if you don't know basic real analysis ... (But I come from a country where you don't "handpick" your topics and the curriculum is very much linear - probably a Bourbaki legacy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "real" Laurent series for $3/(x^2 - 5 x + 4)$ on $(-4,-1) \cup (1,4)$ is just the restriction to that domain of the Laurent series for $3/(z^2 - 5 z + 4)$ on the annulus $1 < |z| < 4$.  But there's no advantage in looking at the real version: it's easier to understand the complex version of Laurent series than the real version.